# How can I view the SQL generated by Anorm?

Tags: scala, anorm

I am trying out anorm to execute a number of insert statements, and then return the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. But I am getting an error saying my SQL syntax is invalid.

Can anyone tell me how to check and see what the final generated SQL that is sent ty MySQL looks like?

Comment: Anorm is not generated SQL. It prepares parameters, like `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. You can check the SQL statement by copying the string passed to `SQL(...)` and replacing by hand parameter placeholders by test values, so you can execute the statement manually.

Comment: That is, good luck testing your application using Anorm...

Answer (score 2):

Anorm doesn't really generate SQL, you do. But there is a way to log the exact queries that are sent over the wire to the console (after the statements are prepared, assuming you're using Anorm within Play).

Assuming you're using a single database called `default` (the default configuration), add the following to your `application.conf`:

```
 db.default.logStatements=true
```

Then you can save the following to `conf/logger.xml`:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.jolbox.bonecp" level="NONE">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="play" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="application" level="NONE">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger> 

</configuration>
```

The key line in the file is related to BoneCP logging, but we want to put in lines for the application and play loggers as well, so we don't mess up the default logging.

Comment: Should be "db.default.logSql = true" in current anorm versions (play 2.5)

Answer (score 0):

Lack of *any* logging in Anorm sucks a lot.

If your generated SQL is not valid and you are getting mysterious exceptions from your driver then I suggest setting break point somewhere here (`anorm.SimpleSql`):

```scala
def preparedStatement(connection: Connection, getGeneratedKeys: Boolean = false) = {
implicit val res = StatementResource
resource.managed {
  val (psql, vs): (String, Seq[(Int, ParameterValue)]) = Sql.prepareQuery(sql.stmt.tokens, sql.paramsInitialOrder, params, 0, new StringBuilder(), List.empty[(Int, ParameterValue)]).get

  val stmt = if (getGeneratedKeys) connection.prepareStatement(psql, java.sql.Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS) else connection.prepareStatement(psql)

  sql.timeout.foreach(stmt.setQueryTimeout(_))

  vs foreach { case (i, v) => v.set(stmt, i + 1) }

  stmt
}
```

and log `psql`

Comment: Recently I learned about
-Dscala.control.noTraceSuppression=true
if you want to get stack traces from anorm